# Automatically copy files after running the app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

A part of my app manipulates images. For debugging purpose I need to save and look at intermediate stages of those images.

**What I have to do manually :**

After I am done running or debugging the app, I have to manually access the storage:

- open Android Device Monitor, which closes my debug session on the device
- open File Explorer tab
- browse /mnt/shell/emulated/0/DCMI/MyApp
- select the files
- click Pull Files
- select my destination.

It's very long and time consuming.

**How I tried to automate:**

I thought about using command line `adb`, but running `adb devices` from a terminal outputs the following :

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

Without any device listed. After that command, Android Studio cannot list my device anymore, and I have to restart it in order to Run App or Debug App.

**Solution I am looking for:**

So either I save in another location on the device that I can directly access through my desktop's file explorer, either I automate a script that copy the files after running or debugging the app which uses the same adb server session as Android Studio.

**Additional info:**

There are pictures in my DCMI folder, I can access it through the "Photo" app of my phone. But when I plug the device to my computer, the OS explorer shows an empty DCMI folder.

I understand that the MTP mode on the device is givin access to a directory structure that depends on the connected user.

So without rooting the device, perhaps a solution would be to configure the MTP client on my OS (ubuntu) to use the same user account as the one running the app on the phone.

Thanks for your advises

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand the purpose of your comment

Comment: What @greenapps Is trying to say is pretty obvious. Can't you just access those files by connecting your phone to your pc and transfering them into your desktop or something? It's a matter of copy-paste. If you can't do that then you are probably saving those pics on internal-app-specific memory. In that case your device needs to be rooted in order to access those files

Comment: Well thank ... I perfectly understood his comment. What I did not understand is the **purpose** of his comment: why he told me to copy paste manually when I am asking for help to transfer the files automatically. Plus I don't like his tone.

Comment: if the images are not big, why not simply upload to a server? this will automate it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Atif. Cause it's a lot of set-up, and I am looking for a simpler solution

Comment: What Operating System you're running? If it's Mac, have you tried [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/)? And as for the adb, are you running the latest version? It is possible that your adb is older than the API level of your testing device.

Comment: One option will be to save those images in a folder on SD-Card root. That will be easily accessible through you OS explorer. Or save them to media storage. btw DCIM is accessible through USB cable

Comment: @Sufian, I'm on linux and using the Android Device Monitor shipped with Android Studio. adb version 1.0.31

Comment: @AtifFarrukh I save the images in a path given by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` but I don't access the "same" DCIM folder with my OS browser. I understand the MTP is giving you access to a directory structure related to your user account. Perhaps a setting in my OS MTP explorer is in order

Comment: I'm on Mac and my adb version is 1.0.36. It might be possible that the version is different across OSs, but it's better to hit your SDK Manager to update. For linux, you can google for [Android File Transfer for Linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+file+transfer+linux).

Comment: I added a chapter titled "Additional info" in the question, kindly have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had a bug on the device. This is how I solved the problem :

On the phone, I went to Parameters > Users, then I switched to Guest account. Then I switched back to my user account. Now when I plug the device, the file structure MTP gives me access to is the one related to my user, and I can directly access the images from my OS explorer

Comment: Seems like it is one of those "have you restarted the system?" moments. :D

Comment: Yes :) but when using it a second time and the bug is back again. Though I know which direction to investigate next